# Validate json with given keys in Javascript and Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, yup

I have below JSON ,

```
[
 {
  "name":"john",
  "school":"school 2",
  "address":"newyork"
 },
 {
  "name":"peter",
  "school":"school 1",
  "address":"washington"
 }
]
```

here i want to validate below mentioned things,

1 - it should be an array
2 - it must have only 3 fields (name,school,address) not more that or less than these three fields
3 - "school" can be either 'school1' or 'school2' and "address" can be either "newyork" or "washington"

I amneed to do this using react js and javascript

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you using typescript?

Comment: no..I am using javascript and reactjs

Comment: Typescript does this natively. For JS, you will have to write manually

Comment: Are you using yup ?

Comment: yes i will be using yup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simplified function of what you are trying to do

```js
const validateJSON = (json) => {
  if (!Array.isArray(json)) {
    return false;
  }
  for (const element of json) {
    if (Object.keys(element).length !== 3) {
      return false;
    }
    if (element.school !== "school 1" && element.school !== "school 2") {
      return false;
    }
    if (element.address !== "newyork" && element.address !== "washington") {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
};
```

then just use `const isValid = validateJSON(json);`

Comment: thanks for your help,is there any way where we can check json has only "name","school" and "address" keys and no other keys

Answer (score 1):

Validation using `yup`

```
const schema = yup.array()
    .of(
      yup.object().shape({
        name: yup.string().required("Required"),
        school: yup.mixed().oneOf(['school 1','school 2']),
        address: yup.mixed().oneOf(['newyork','washington'])
      }).noUnknown(true)
    )
```

and validate,

```
await schema.validate(your_object).catch(function (err) {
  err.name; // => 'ValidationError'
  err.errors;
});
```

*Note: this validation is not tested*